# Tell computer to clear the answer after it is being printed

Tags: c++

The program is intended to square and add up all the number from 1 to the number I entered. If I just enter one number the answer will be correct, but if I don't stop it and re-open my program the answer for the second number I enter will also add the result from the first number. What am I missing? Please help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int inNum;
int loopCount = 1;
int count;
int sum = 0;

cout << "Enter a number greater than 0 (less than 1 to quit): " << endl;
cin >> inNum;

while ( inNum >= loopCount) {
    for (count=0 ; count <= inNum ; count++ ){
        sum = sum + count * count; 
    }

    cout << "The sum of the squares from 1 to " << inNum << " is " << sum << endl;

    cout << "Enter a number greater than 0 (less than 1 to quit): " << endl;
    cin >> inNum;
}
}
```

Comment: put a `sum = 0;` after your final `cin`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! The solution is so obvious and I still can't figure out!! Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Actually, if you don't use `sum` outside the while loop, I would move the `int sum = 0` into the beginning of the `while` loop. In other words, declare variables a close as possible to first use.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move the declaration of `sum` into your while block,

```
// int sum = 0;
while ( inNum >= loopCount) {
  int sum = 0; // <-- or just sum = 0; and keep the declaration outside the loop
```

Another (as mentioned in the comments) is to reset `sum` at the end of the loop body.

Comment: Thank you for your help Elliott, I am wondering if I do it this way will it makes the program run a little bit faster. I notice a lag whenever I start the program. ( running speed is not a concern for this assignment, but I just want create an efficient program. )

Comment: @WilsonYu Probably not, this is a trivial change to resolve a bug; not a serious change in the algorithm.